Cloning a git repo over https through ngrok
My application clones git repos over https (ssh is not an option) using basic authentication like this:
git clone https://oauth2:TOKEN_VALUE@github.com/acme/repo

I am now trying to clone a repo that lives in a private network exposed through an ngrok proxy.  I started the ngrok agent like this:
ngrok http https://github.com

Then I attempted the clone
git clone https://oauth2:TOKEN_VALUE@NGROK_DOMAIN/acme/repo

The call returns an authentication error

Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for https://NGROK_DOMAIN/acme/repo/

In the ngrok dashboard, I see one request
GET /acme/repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: NGROK_DOMAIN
User-Agent: git/2.39.3
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Git-Protocol: version=2
Pragma: no-cache
X-Forwarded-For: <my IP address>
X-Forwarded-Host: NGROK_DOMAIN
X-Forwarded-Proto: https

And its 301 Redirect response:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://github.com/acme/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

Why isn't clone working?  At first I thought the basic auth creds are not being passed on.  However if I try to clone without passing the creds, like this:
git clone https://NGROK_DOMAIN/acme/repo

Then I get a different error message that does not mention authentication, but does mention github.com!

Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository https://github.com/acme/repo.git/ not found

How can I execute a git clone over https through an Ngrok proxy?

The reason it was failing going through NGROK is that GitHub would reject the forwarded request when it saw the request header host: NGROK_DOMAIN.
Once I successfully rewrote that header to host: github.com during proxying, things worked as expected
